# Equivalent of GetCommand() function of (Linq to Sql) in (Linq to Entity)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a generic function written for Linq to Sql.

Some code is:

```
string sqlCmd = dc.GetCommand(q).CommandText;
{
   foreach (System.Data.Common.DbParameter dbp in dc.GetCommand(q).Parameters)
   {
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter(dbp.ParameterName, dbp.Value));
   }
}
```

where dc is a DataContext. I am using ObjectContext. **q is System.Linq.IQueryable**. So inspite of **dc.GetCommand(q).CommandText**. What should I use know. And similarly for **DbParameter**. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF doesn't have equivalent to `GetCommand`. If you want to have access to parameters try to use [EF Provider Wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) (check sample for Tracing).